# How to display live location of user within a map in an android app?

Tags: java, android, mysql, dictionary, location

I am working on an application module where the module interacts with user directly and tracks down the location of the user from the app and stores the same in the database as `Latitude` and `Longitude` field. I am using `MYSql databse`.

I have used a concept where I am making **repeated `Web Service`** request to get the latest lat long from the database as well as pushing the same to the database to store the same using **API** endpoint. But the same is not efficient and drains battery a lot.

So I would like to know how to make a location aware app which displays live location of the user without calling the end point repeatedly.

**Indirectly I would like to know how an app like OLA or UBER displays cabs nearby also shows accurate location of the cab moving from one point to the another.**

TIA

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You dont have to make repeated network calls to push the location to your server. You can do the following two things based on which was achieved early:

1) Push locations every 40-60 secs seconds( The interval is up to you)

2) Push locations when user has moved, say about a 100 meters.(Again, the distance is up to you)

To sum up, you need to be observing time and distance  parallely in your code and then make your network call.

Comment: I meant the same when I said "repeated" call

Comment: Well then there is no other way!

Comment: Are you sure of it or you don't know about it?

Comment: Are you aware of websocket?

Comment: No, i know about Android and iOS.

Comment: I'm talking about the same

Comment: I think if u be clear in what you are 'saying' and what you are 'actually doing', it will be helpful for anyone in the community to understand and answer you properly! That's why there were down votes to your question.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is looking for a solution, here is what worked for me

I have used a relatime DB ex `Firebase` or `rethinkdb`. Now in `OnLocationChange` update the values in the database or add the same. Make sure that the object you want to show always shows the last item. Thus it will move to the new location.